# "Remote" connection to a local MYSQL database on LAN

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, connectivity

I have a mySQL (5.5.38) server running on my desktop (windows 7), I can connect just fine into any of the servers Users, and skip-networking is off when checked via show variables. I am trying to give another family member access on their laptop, but get error 10060 each time (could not connect)

I have tried giving them an account from host %, and another one from their local IP, though neither is working. I have tried having them connect to each of the following with both accounts - my actual IP, my local IP, and the hostname variable for the server. each connection returns error 10060.

Comment: Did you check firewall rules in the remote machine?

Comment: Firewall was not active

Comment: Most common causes would include being behind a NAT or not being bound to the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - Windows firewall had to be turned ON and then have the ports forwarded. Windows firewall being off was filtering the ports.